# Assert that current thread does not hold a CRITICAL_SECTION lock

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, critical-section

I have an object that maintains a list; one of the helper methods needs to

- lock the list
- find the first element
- unlock the list
- notify another thread to start a cleanup operation
- wait on the other thread to finish
- repeat this until the list is empty.

The cleanup operation removes the object from the list from the other thread, thus it needs to lock the list in between.

This works fine as long as the helper is not called with the lock on the list already held as then the unlock operation will not actually allow the other thread to access the list, so I'd like to flag an error in this case.

As far as I've understood, the `CRITICAL_SECTION` API does not provide an officially supported way to query whether the current process holds this object, so I'm considering "hack-ish" approaches (after all, it's a debugging aid and not intended to go into production code):

Variant 1 is to check the `OwningThread` field of the `CRITICAL_SECTION` structure, but I wonder whether there is a guarantee that this field is

- always containing a thread ID from the same number space as `GetCurrentThreadId()` results
- always updated when any thread takes the lock
- always cleared when my own thread releases the lock

Variant 2 is to lock the `CRITICAL_SECTION` and then examine the `RecursionCount`; this assumes that the recursion counter has a fixed start value.

Is there anything that I have missed that I could use to build a somewhat future-proof (that is, it will break noisily in a line of code that is near to the comments where I explain it all) assertion statement that the current thread is *not* the holder of a certain `CRITICAL_SECTION`?

Comment: You can't rely on any of the fields of a critical section struct since they are implementation dependent and that implementation has changed in recent times.

Comment: Your design sounds way off. You are trying to detect whether the calling thread already has the lock? If you don't know that locks any given piece of code holds then you've little chance of being able to write correct and deadlock free code.

Comment: I am fairly certain that I don't hold the lock. I need something to place inside an `assert(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Make your own critical section that provides such a feature. Use it in your debug builds. In release builds, use the regular critical section.

One simple way is to use two critical sections and an owner field. Acquire works like this:

1. Acquire first critical section.
2. Acquire second critical section.
3. Set owner to this thread.
4. Release second critical section.

Release works like this:

1. Acquire second critical section.
2. Set owner to none.
3. Release first critical section.
4. Release second critical section.

Assert works like this:

1. Acquire second critical section.
2. Assert owner is not this thread.
3. Release second critical section.

**Update**: There's a bug in the above. It mishandles this case: lock, lock, unlock, assert that we don't hold the critical section but we do. The fix is probably to keep a "lock count". You don't have to set the CS to "unowned" with the lock count. If the lock count is zero, it's unowned. So the assert paths "unowned or owner not this thread".

Comment: Actually you don't need the second critical section. You can use the original critical section to protect itself.

Comment: @RaymondChen If you have an atomic operation to check the owner, you can. Otherwise, you either have to acquire the main critical section to assert or you have to rely on word tearing not being an issue with the owner value. (In some cases, that's not a problem. Maybe in most cases.)

Comment: Yes, it assumes that the "current owner" field is properly aligned. But since the `CRITICAL_SECTION` must already be aligned, this is easy to enforce by simply putting the "current owner" next to the `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Until your code has to run on a platform whose thread IDs are wider than you can fetch atomically. (I would consider that a platform-specific optimization, appropriate only with suitable `ifdef` guards to ensure it was only used on a platform where it was suitable. Or at least I would if this wasn't going to be compiled out on releases anyway. Since this is debug-only code, I think it's fine. If it breaks due to word tearing or something like that, you're debugging anyway.)

Comment: The code is already Win32-specific due to the use of `CRITICAL_SECTION`. Win32 guarantees that suitably-aligned `DWORD`s can be fetched atomically.

Comment: @RaymondChen But there's no guarantee that future Windows platforms might also have a CRITICAL_SECTION but not allow atomic fetches of aligned DWORDs. A lot of code was unnecessarily difficult to port to 64-bit Windows because of very similar assumptions and there's no way to know now which assumptions are safe. If you rely on specific platform details, you should clearly indicate such in your code or it may break subtly on future platforms.

Comment: Breaking atomic access to `DWORD`s would effectively break all Win32 code on the planet. Unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like that

```
class CriticalSection
{
private:
  CRITICAL_SECTION section_;
  unsigned int owning_thread_id_;
  unsigned int lock_count_;

public:
  CriticalSection() 
  {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&section_);
    owning_thread_id_ = 0;
    lock_count_ = 0;

  }
  ~CriticalSection()
  {
    DeleteCriticalSection(&section_);
  }

  void enter()
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(&section_);
    owning_thread_id_ = GetCurrentThreadId();
    lock_count_ ++;
  }
  void leave()
  {

    if(  GetCurrentThreadId() == owning_thread_id_ )
    {
      lock_count_ --;
      if( lock_count_ == 0 )
        owning_thread_id_ = 0;
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&section_);
  }

  bool tryEnter() 
  { 
    if( TryEnterCriticalSection(&section_))
    {
      owning_thread_id_ = GetCurrentThreadId();
      lock_count_ ++;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool isCurrentThreadEntered()
  {
    return GetCurrentThreadId() == owning_thread_id_;
  }

  int getLockCount() { return lock_count_; }
  unsigned int getOwningThreadID() { return owning_thread_id_; }

};
```